# How to label pandas series using dictionary keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas series(data) with  column name `description`, and created a new column `Label` which simply checks if a dictionary key exist in the `description` column, if it does it labels the description based on the key found e.g

```
description                         Label

427096  alat airtime recharge       bills
1093255 alat nip transfer          transfers
549792  alat transfer              transfers
1163429 wema ussd transfer         transfers
```

dictionary

```
   labels = { #transfer
          "tnf":"transfers", "trsf":"transfers","trtr":"transfers", "trans":"transfers",
 
           #bills
           "otp":"bills","fee":"bills","charge":"bills",

           #airtime
          "recharge":"airtime","airtime":"airtime","top-up":"airtime",
      }
```

Here is function that does the checking:

```
labs = []
    # Labelling the transaction according to the dictionary defined
    for i in data:
        f = 0
        #check if j is in data[i]
        for j in list(labels.keys()):
            if j in i:
                labs.append(labels[j])
                f = 1
                break
        if f == 0:
            labs.append("others")
    df["Label"] = pd.DataFrame(labs)
```

The major issue here is that the function doesn't check for **exact** match, keys like `airtime recharge` should be labelled as airtime and also the dictionary key `trans` labels transaction as `transfer`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you aren't checking for exact match, you're just checking if a substring is in the string. so things like `'charge'` in `'recharge'` will return `True`.

So you could either use regex or just split the description into a list and check if the word is in the list.

Not the most efficient way, but you could do something ike this:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([['alat airtime recharge'],
                  ['alat nip transfer'],
                  ['alat transfer'] ,
                  ['wema ussd transfer']],columns=['description'])


labels = { #transfer
          "tnf":"transfers", "trsf":"transfers","trtr":"transfers", "trans":"transfers",
 
           #bills
           "otp":"bills","fee":"bills","charge":"bills",

           #airtime
          "recharge":"airtime","airtime":"airtime","top-up":"airtime",
      }


labs = []
data = df['description']
# Labelling the transaction according to the dictionary defined
for i in data:
    check_list = i.split()
    f = 0
    #check if j is in data[i]
    loop = True
    while loop==True:
        for j in list(labels.keys()):
            if loop==False:
                break
            for x in check_list:
                if loop==False:
                    break
                if x.startswith(j):
                    labs.append(labels[j])
                    f = 1
                    loop=False
    if f == 0:
        labs.append("others")
df["Label"] = pd.DataFrame(labs)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
             description      Label
0  alat airtime recharge    airtime
1      alat nip transfer  transfers
2          alat transfer  transfers
3     wema ussd transfer  transfers
```

Comment: thanks for the update, the `x.startswith(j)` will definitely match based on any description that starts with the keys, like you said a reqex or just splitting description into a list would work best in this particular case.